# Calculate Total Number of Row's Value

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a SQL table that looks like this:

```
id | value
-----------------------
1  | 5
2  | 5
3  | 6
```

I want to count the `value` of every rows.
In this example the output should be `16`.

What query should I use to count the total value of the rows?

Comment: `SELECT SUM(value) FROM table_name;`

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more about COUNT() Function there.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp